# Create a web service with CodeIgniter

Tags: web-services, codeigniter

im using CodeIgniter 1.7 framework to make my Website.
Another team do the mobile version for iPhone.
So the other team ask me to do a web service for authentification.
They tell that they will send me :

```
POST REQUEST 
Input : login , password, push_token
if failure authentification -> Output HTTP : error code 0
if success -> Output XML :
<DATA>
 <User id='id_user' title='..' first_name='' last_name='' email='' postal='' country_id=''/> 
</DATA>
```

Basically i have this function for authentification:

```
function check_login($username="", $password="")
{
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
...
...
}
```

im looking into this post [Codeigniter web services](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9696009/874800) but i don't understand how its really work because im new in webservice.

Answer (score 5):

I would consider using json as a sole output with one value being `TRUE` or `FALSE` depending on success. It's easier to handle, and all it requires is for your site to be in utf8.

If your `check_login()` returns `TRUE`, use that as the condition for success.

Example of reply:

```
/* Class etc. */

function do_login() {
    $arr_json = array('success' => FALSE);
    if ($this->login_library->check_login()) {
        $arr_json['success'] = TRUE;
        $arr_json['user_id'] = $this->login_library->user_id;
    }
    echo json_encode($arr_json);
}
```

`login_library` is just an example for your library which does the login. The reply they receive only needs to be decoded through `json_decode()`. And then simply check if the key `success` is `TRUE` or not.

If needed, have an extra key called `error_message` or similiar, and you can run all post-values through [**form_validation**](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html). Then you can also have `$arr_json['error_message'] = trim(validation_errors('', "\n"));` before the `echo` aswell.

Answer (score 2):

You should definately look into Phil Sturgeons CodeIgniter Rest Server:

> https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver

There's a pretty good documentation. He also made a screencast about it: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2011/03/video-set-up-a-rest-api-with-codeigniter

Furthermore you could have a look at this article, where Adam Whitney explains his approach:

> *Building a RESTful Service using CodeIgniter*
>
> http://adamwhitney.net/blog/?p=707